# Android - Centre Text Relative to Screen and not View

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, textview

I have a number of textviews in a linear layout, which itself is sitting within a linear layout within a relative layout (see structure below). I am positioning the top level linear layout to the right of a button in the view by using `android:layout_toRightOf` to stop the textview overlapping the button when the text is too long.

What I want to do is centre the text in the textviews relative to the entire view, not the linear layout within which it sits (i.e centre it relative to the screen width). I have tried using layout_gravity set to centre in the textview and the relative layout) but with no effect.

Can anyone suggest how to centre the text in this way ?

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/headerLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@drawable/purple"
        android:minHeight="64dip"
        android:visibility="visible" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="2dip"

            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/backButton"

            android:gravity="center|center_vertical|fill_vertical"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/headerTextLayout"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="48dip"
                android:layout_marginRight="48dip"

                android:gravity="center|center_vertical|fill_vertical"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/headerText"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text=""
                    android:textColor="@color/white_color"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:paddingLeft="16dip"
                    android:paddingRight="16dip"
                    android:typeface="sans"
                    android:singleLine="true"/>
```

Comment: why don't you add your textview inside your main relative layout with centerInParent="true"

Comment: Ah sorry - it's because there are more textviews in the layout.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<TextView
                    android:id="@+id/headerText"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text=""
                    **android:textAlignment="gravity"**
                    android:textColor="@color/white_color"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:paddingLeft="16dip"
                    android:paddingRight="16dip"
                    android:typeface="sans"
                    android:singleLine="true"/>
```

Comment: Didn't have any effect sadly.